# Density of screen in iOS and Universal WIndows App

Tags: xamarin.ios, uwp, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

Hi I need to know the density of screen in windows 10/8/8.1 and iOS.
I got screen density in Android using DisplayMetrics but I find no such option/property available in UWP and iOS.
So Is there any property through which I can get screen density in UWP and IOS.

Comment: Take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/40225241/5216815 ?

Comment: This is also a nice read - http://stackoverflow.com/a/33846405/5216815

Comment: @MatthewRegul but how to get density of screen in windows case (8,8.1,10)

Comment: That's the real question, I still need to figure that out myself.  I'll reply if I find anything.

Comment: @MatthewRegul ok thanks.

Comment: Hopefully the code below works for you.

Comment: Sonali, were you able to solve your issue?

Comment: @MatthewRegul yes.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

UPDATE - June 8th 2018

## Xamarin has released Xamarin.Essentials!

> Xamarin.Essentials provides developers with cross-platform APIs for their mobile applications.
>
> Android, iOS, and UWP offer unique operating system and platform APIs that developers have access to all in C# leveraging Xamarin. Xamarin.Essentials provides a single cross-platform API that works with any Xamarin.Forms, Android, iOS, or UWP application that can be accessed from shared code no matter how the user interface is created.
> https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials

---

You can now query the device's display information without having to manage all of the individual platform code pieces.

**Device Display Information** - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/device-display

#### How-To:

Add a reference to Xamarin.Essentials in your class:

```cs
using Xamarin.Essentials;
```

The following information is exposed through the API:

```cs
// Get Metrics
var mainDisplayInfo = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo;

// Orientation (Landscape, Portrait, Square, Unknown)
var orientation = mainDisplayInfo.Orientation;

// Rotation (0, 90, 180, 270)
var rotation = mainDisplayInfo.Rotation;

// Width (in pixels)
var width = mainDisplayInfo.Width;

// Height (in pixels)
var height = mainDisplayInfo.Height;

// Screen density
var density = mainDisplayInfo.Density;
```

---

#### Useful Links:

- (Github) **Xamarin.Essentials** - https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials
- (Blog) **Xamarin.Essentials** - https://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-essentials-cross-platform-apis-mobile-apps/
- (Docs) **Getting Started with Essentials** - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/get-started

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

#### Original Post (Before Xamarin.Essentials existed)

Below, I'm storing the specific OS's screen details in `static` vars, located in the Xamarin Forms `App` class

These all appear to work in my testing.

*(copy/pasted from my github page - https://github.com/mattregul/Xamarin_Screensize)*

### Android (MainActivity.cs) - [Jump to Github Page](https://github.com/mattregul/Xamarin_Screensize/blob/master/screensize/screensize/screensize/screensize.Droid/MainActivity.cs#L22-L36)

```
// Store off the device sizes, so we can access them within Xamarin Forms
// Screen Width = WidthPixels / Density
// Screen Height = HeightPixels / Density

App.DisplayScreenWidth  = (double)Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels / (double)Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density;
App.DisplayScreenHeight = (double)Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels / (double)Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density; 
App.DisplayScaleFactor  = (double)Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density;
```

### iOS (AppDelegate.cs) - [Jump to Github Page](https://github.com/mattregul/Xamarin_Screensize/blob/master/screensize/screensize/screensize/screensize.iOS/AppDelegate.cs#L27-L38)

```
// Store off the device sizes, so we can access them within Xamarin Forms
App.DisplayScreenWidth  = (double)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width;
App.DisplayScreenHeight = (double)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height;
App.DisplayScaleFactor  = (double)UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale;
```

#### Note In all Windows examples `screensize` is the root project namespace

### UWP (App.xaml.cs) - [Jump to Github Page](https://github.com/mattregul/Xamarin_Screensize/blob/master/screensize/screensize/screensize/screensize.UWP/App.xaml.cs#L60-L85)

```
// You decided which is best for you...
//  Do you want Size of the App's View
//      or
//  Do you want the Display's resolution 
// ######################################

// Size of App's view
screensize.App.DisplayScreenHeight = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().VisibleBounds.Height;
screensize.App.DisplayScreenWidth = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().VisibleBounds.Width;

// Size of screen's resolution
//screensize.App.DisplayScreenWidth = Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().ScreenHeightInRawPixels;
//screensize.App.DisplayScreenHeight = Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().ScreenWidthInRawPixels;

// Pixels per View Pixel
// - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/design-and-ui-intro#effective-pixels-and-scaling
// - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/screen-sizes-and-breakpoints-for-responsive-design
screensize.App.DisplayScaleFactor = Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().RawPixelsPerViewPixel;
```

### Windows Phone 8.1 (App.xaml.cs) - [Jump to Github Page](https://github.com/mattregul/Xamarin_Screensize/blob/master/screensize/screensize/screensize/screensize.WinPhone/App.xaml.cs#L62-L77)

```
// Size of App's view
screensize.App.DisplayScreenHeight = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().VisibleBounds.Height;
screensize.App.DisplayScreenWidth = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().VisibleBounds.Width;

// Pixels per View Pixel
// - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/design-and-ui-intro#effective-pixels-and-scaling
// - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/screen-sizes-and-breakpoints-for-responsive-design
screensize.App.DisplayScaleFactor = Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().RawPixelsPerViewPixel;
```

### Windows 8.1 (App.xaml.cs) - [Jump to Github Page](https://github.com/mattregul/Xamarin_Screensize/blob/master/screensize/screensize/screensize/screensize.Windows/App.xaml.cs#L61-L72)

```
// Size of App's view
screensize.App.DisplayScreenHeight = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
screensize.App.DisplayScreenWidth = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
screensize.App.DisplayScaleFactor = 1; // No scaling here?  If you find a scaling for Windows 8.1, please let me know :)
```

### Xamarin Forms Page (App.cs) - [Jump to Github Page](https://github.com/mattregul/Xamarin_Screensize/blob/master/screensize/screensize/screensize/screensize/App.cs#L10-L44)

```
namespace screensize
{
    public class App : Application
    {
        public static double DisplayScreenWidth = 0f;
        public static double DisplayScreenHeight = 0f;
        public static double DisplayScaleFactor = 0f;

        public App()
        {

            string ScreenDetails = Device.OS.ToString() + " Device Screen Size:\n" +
                $"Width: {DisplayScreenWidth}\n" +
                $"Height: {DisplayScreenHeight}\n" +
                $"Scale Factor: {DisplayScaleFactor}";

            // The root page of your application
            var content = new ContentPage
            {
                Title = "Xamarin_GetDeviceScreensize",
                Content = new StackLayout
                {
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                    Children = {
                        new Label {
                            HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                            FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize (NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label)),
                            Text = ScreenDetails
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            MainPage = new NavigationPage(content);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This list lists the ios device dpi information. You can also use [`GBDeviceInfo`](https://github.com/lmirosevic/GBDeviceInfo) thrid-party tool to get the screen density for IOS device like this `[GBDeviceInfo deviceInfo].displayInfo.pixelsPerInch;`

IOS:

```
   iPhones
iPhone 1/3G/3GS           320 x  480    163 ppi
iPhone 4/4S               640 x  940    326 ppi
iPhone 5/5C/5S            640 x 1136    326 ppi
iPhone 6/6S               750 x 1334    326 ppi
iPhone 6 Plus/6S Plus    1080 x 1920    401 ppi
  Without downsampling:  1242 x 2208    461 ppi

Except for the 6th generation (= 5th) iPod touch,
all the models are equal to their iPhone counterparts

iPads
iPad 1/2                  768 x 1024    132 ppi
iPad 3/4/Air/Air 2       1536 x 2048    264 ppi
iPad Mini 1               768 x 1024    163 ppi
iPad Mini 2/3/4          1536 x 2048    326 ppi
iPad Pro                 2737 x 2048    264 ppi

Apple Watches
Apple Watch 38 mm         272 x  340    326 ppi
Apple Watch 42 mm         312 x  390    326 ppi
```

I found [API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.display.displayinformation.aspx) in the UWP to retrieve the device dpi. `Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayInformation`. You can try it.

Comment: I used `(double)UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale;` it always returns one. Why??

Comment: how can i get xdpi and ydpi in ios?

Comment: By default, The value of  `MainScreen.Scale` is always one because of the original displaying settings of your device.

Comment: ok then how can i get xdpi and ydpi in ios?  @Nico Zhu - MSFT

Comment: Please try to use `[GBDeviceInfo deviceInfo].displayInfo.pixelsPerInch` api in your ios project.

Comment: couldn't find this package in nuget package manager. @Nico Zhu - MSFT

Comment: The `GBDeviceInfo` thrid-party tool is only available in ios project coding by object-c.

Comment: but how will I use this in my portable xamarin project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138704/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-sonali).